# Image steganography decoding

Tags: image-processing, steganography

Is it possible to decode the data embedded into an image, if a stego-image is printed on a paper and captured by camera and then providing the captured image to steganography decoder?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the steganography system used to encode the message would have to be carefully designed to support that use case, and the amount of data you could encode in a single image would be very limited.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer